# How can i display an active list in a dropdownmenu

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I want to extend my dropdownmenu with this script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('li.active>ul').css('display','block');

  $("ul.parent>li:not(.active)").mouseenter(function(){
    $("ul.parent li.active>ul").css("display","none"); 
  });

  $("ul.parent>li:not(.active)").mouseleave(function(){
    $("ul.parent li.active>ul").css("display","block"); 
  });


  $("ul.level-2>li:not(.active)").mouseenter(function(){
    $("ul.level-2 li.active>ul").css("display","none"); 
  });

  $("ul.level-2>li:not(.active)").mouseleave(function(){
    $("ul.level-2 li.active>ul").css("display","block"); 
  });


});
```

It works, but is there any cleaner solution than this, even for more levels?

Comment: can you show us your markup?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using `hover()` - `toggle()` and `parent()` but depends on your markup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.active-trail>ul').css('display','block');
    $("ul > li:not(.active-trail)").hover(function(){
      $(this).parent().find("li.active>ul").toggle(); 
    });
})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! It`s great, but this script works for the top and 2nd level, but not for the 3. If the ul has in the 3. level an "active" class, the other level 3 lists overlap it.

Comment: @Bruno Hi that's why I say depends on your markup can you show that? and maybe paste it in a http://jsfidle.net

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/pF9JJ/ There is all ok, but on my testpage i still get the error. When the 3. level is active and i leave the menupoint, surround with the cursor the menu and go with it from the top to the 3. level list, the active is not shown, but both lists which have no active class are shown when i now leave the menu.

Comment: So I see this working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/pF9JJ/1/ you say you have a problem on your site maybe some cSS additional? @Bruno